# Data from annotation callout bubble on map view in ios

Tags: ios, maps

I am displaying the annotations with callout bubbles on map view with respect to data base data. If I click on the annotation pin, the callout showing the that address. I am doing this on every pin annotation on map view. But while I am passing that data, what I have displaying on callout to next view, only single address going to next view as every time.

Please give me the solution.

Comment: Are you saying that only the first line of the address is shown in the Callout view?

Answer (score 0):

You will have the function calloutAccessoryControlTapped called when tapped on Callout.
Here you normally must be creating an instance of the Next View - Controller  and navigating to it via push or model.
You will pass all the information to be passed to the Next view in this function

```
NextViewController.locationdetails= someLocationObject;
```

Hope this is clear.Let me know if your question was different.